# Display Enumeration-Array-Values in the Matlab Variable Editor

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, enumeration

I have an array of Enumerations in Matlab and want to see its *element-values* in the Variable Editor.

Matlab displays the enumeration-objects of the array in the editor only with the class of the objects:

```
<1x1 EnumLetter><1x1 EnumLetter><1x1....
```

The variable editor should show the enumeration value instead:

```
<enumA><enumA><enumB><enumA>...
```

Like it is displayed at the command window:

```
myEnums =
    enumA    enumB    enumA    enumB
```

My definition of the enumeration:

```
classdef EnumLetter
   enumeration
      enumA
      enumB
   end
end
```

Is this possible, without using `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay` which unfortunately doesn't work at my Matlab2011b because of an overshadow error. See, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152029/how-can-i-display-enumeration-value-in-matlab-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703121/customize-display-of-an-enumeration-class).

### A near solution:

If there are values linked to the enumerations, the values are displayed in the Variable Editor:

```
1 1 2 1
```

The Definition of the enumeration with values:

```
classdef EnumLetter < uint8
   enumeration
      enumA (1)
      enumB (2)
   end
end
```

Unfortunately the `char` type may not be superclass...